# cannot load such file -- test_helper if test case run using 'ruby' instead of 'rake test'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

If I run test case:

```
ruby test/models/chat_bot/option_test.rb
```

I get error:

```
/home/anuja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)
```

and it works if I run test as follow:

```
rake test test/models/chat_bot/option_test.rb
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to add your test directory to Ruby's load path. Otherwise Ruby doesn't know where to look to find `test_helper`. To add to the load path, use the `-I` option:

```
ruby -Itest test/models/chat_bot/option_test.rb
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding absolute path: require ''./test/test_helper'' instead of require 'test_helper'.

Answer (score 7):

It is fixed by adding absolute path:

```
require './test/test_helper'
```

instead of:

```
require 'test_helper'
```

wherever we require the same. And then I can run test case without any parameter:

```
ruby test/models/xyz/option_test.rb
```

Comment: Now 2019.  The popular "how tos" don't work - hours with error after error w/o ever getting to the job at hand.  Until the buggy-test frameworks are fixed (with automated setup), the best workaround is to manually-include each file by absolute-path.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow running `rails test <test_file_path>` from my project's root solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the test as the rails guide says:

```
bin/rails test test/controllers/CONTROLLERNAME_controller_test.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby must know where `test_helper` exist.

Either like Matt said on CLI with ruby like

```sh
ruby -Itest test/models/chat_bot/option_test.rb
```

or if run from a rake task, the same must be done in the Rakefile

```rb
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"          # <--- this!
  t.test_files = FileList["test/**/*_test.rb"]
end
desc "Run tests"
```

as documented [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Rake/TestTask.html).

Then it should work fine to include `test_helper` in `test/models/chat_bot/option_test.rb` like

```rb
require 'test_helper'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../test", __dir__)
```

before

```
require "test_helper"
```

It adds the test folder to the global variable LOAD_PATH. Which is used for searching Ruby scripts and extension libraries used by Kernel#load and Kernel#require.